# Implicit conversion not working in C++ when function is a friend of class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion, friend-function

I'm using a library in C++ which provides a certain class, lets call it C1. My own class (C2) is similar to C1, there is a function to convert C1 to C2 and vise versa. Since C1 overrides all the operators I require in C2, my idea is to define a Constructor in C2 which takes C1 and calls the conversion function. Additionally the casting operator to cast C2 to C1 is overridden. In my understanding, the compiler should now be able to do stuff with C2 that is written for C1, due to the implicit conversion between the Types. However, when I use for example std::cout, the compiler is not able to see, that C2 can be converted to C1 and the << operator is implemented for C1. Explicit casting works and also stuff like C2 a; C1 b = C2, so I assume I correctly implemented the casting. To narrow down the problem I created an mcve. The following code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

class C1 {
public:
    int v;
    C1(int v) {this->v = v;}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const C1& c) {
    s << c.v;
    return s;
}

class C2 {
public:
    int v;
    C2(int count) {this->v = count;}
    C2(C1 c) {this->v = c.v;}
    operator C1() {return C1(this->v);}
};

int main() {
    C1 a(0);
    C2 b = a;
    C1 c = b;
    std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I move the << operator inside C2 (it is done like this in the library I'm using), I get "error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream’} and ‘C2’)"

The respective code:

```
#include <iostream>

class C1 {
public:
    int v;
    C1(int v) {this->v = v;}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const C1& c) {
        s << c.v;
        return s;
    }
};

class C2 {
public:
    int v;
    C2(int count) {this->v = count;}
    C2(C1 c) {this->v = c.v;}
    operator C1() {return C1(this->v);}
};

int main() {
    C1 a(0);
    C2 b = a;
    C1 c = b;
    std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this not working? In my understanding the compiler has all the required information: There is an implementation for the << operator working with C1 and it is possible to convert C2 to C1.

Comment: The link from @super has teeth. I'd definitely read that were I you.